# python list search and concatenation performance

Tags: python, performance, coding-style

I'm new to Python and looking for some critiques on the simple DFS code I wrote:

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):
    return depthFirstSearchRec(problem.getStartState(), problem)

def depthFirstSearchRec(currentState, problem, visited=[]):
    if currentState in visited:
        return None
    else:
        visited.append(currentState)

    if problem.isGoalState(currentState):
        return []

    for successor, action, _ in problem.getSuccessors(currentState):
        actions = depthFirstSearchRec(successor, problem)

        if actions is not None:
            return [action] + actions

    return None
```

Qeustions:

1. Is searching a list using "in" keyword an O(n) operation in Python? If so, what is the best way of doing this?
2. Is adding to the head of a list O(1), like adding to the head of a linked list, or O(n), like adding to the head of an array? If it is O(n), what is the best way of doing this?
3. Please feel free to point out any "bad" coding practices, if any

Comment: For feedback on coding practices in working code try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for info on time complexity of operations on Python builtin types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python `list` is an array that's compact in memory, like, say, a C++'s `std::vector`.  Therefore, the `in` operator is `O(N)` and adding to anywhere but the end of a `list` is also `O(N)`.  The solution is to use a different data structure -- there are a **lot**! -- depending on what is it you're trying to accomplish.

Assuming your `states` are hashable (they'd better be, if you hope for good performance!), `visited` should be a `set` -- adding to a set and using the `in` operator on it are both `O(1)` (as the set is internally implemented as a hash table).

As for `actions`, the simplest idea is probably to use a `collections.deque` rather than a list -- that double-ended queue is `O(1)` for appending or removing at either end (though a list is much faster, and also `O(1)`, if all additions and removals are at the right-end).

Comment: Accoring to [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), list `in` and insert are both O(n).

Comment: Oops, a typo, fixing, tx.